# How to add Header and Footer in a word document using POI api?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried following code to add footer in my document but it is not working fine.

```
  CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
    CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
    CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
    CTText textt = ctr.addNewT();
    textt.setStringValue( " Page 1" );
    XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph( ctp, document );
    XWPFParagraph[] newparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    newparagraphs[0] = codePara;
    CTSectPr sectPr1 = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( document,sectPr1 );

headerFooterPolicy.createFooter( STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, newparagraphs );
```

I am using following jars to generate my document. Please help...

1. poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
2. poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
3. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
4. poi-scratchpad-3.10-FINAL-20140208

Comment: What do you mean by "not working fine"? Works partly? Gives an error? Shows up wrong? Also, there's no code shown saving the file, could it be as simple as that?

Comment: Could you please help to complete the code? Please tell me how to save this to file?

Comment: To save the file, it's the same for whatever format you use - just call [write(OutputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The problem is not with your header / footer code. The code in your question looks fine for doing what you want. In case you do want to do a bit more though, the best reference that springs to mind is the [unit tests for headers and footers in Apache POI](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFHeader.java), which cover more use cases

What your code doesn't do is write the file out after you have made your changes!

You just need to add in a call to [write(OutputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) at the end of your code, and you'll be done. Something like

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WithHeader.docx");
document.write(out);
out.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

[Adding footer to ms word using POI api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250065/adding-footer-to-ms-word-using-poi-api)

```
CTP ctp = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTR ctr = ctp.addNewR();
        CTRPr rpr = ctr.addNewRPr();
        CTText textt = ctr.addNewT();
        textt.setStringValue( " Page 1" );
        XWPFParagraph codePara = new XWPFParagraph( ctp, document );
        XWPFParagraph[] newparagraphs = new XWPFParagraph[1];
        newparagraphs[0] = codePara;
        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( document, sectPr );
        headerFooterPolicy.createFooter( STHdrFtr.DEFAULT, newparagraphs );
```

Comment: This answer should have some explanation of the snippet.